# Div is automatically 100% wide

Tags: html, css

I have a simple Question. Why is a  not automatically the size of its content? Like for instance this:

```
<html>

    <div style="margin:auto; background:red;">Test</div>

</html>
```

Returns in `width:100%`, although I would like the word "Test" to be simply centered. Any ideas?

Comment: Because one is a block element and the other is inline.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has to do with the fundamentals of HTML. There are [`block` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) and [`inline` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). Block level elements, *by their very nature*, will always take up the full width of their containing element. The only way to change that is through CSS.

If you're looking to wrap a word, and only that work, in a border or background color then you need to use an inline element. For example:

```css
div,
span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<span>Test</span>
```

The question about using `margin: 0 auto` and why it doesn't center is because you need to specify a width. To center the text withing a full width DIV you will need to apply `text-align: center;`. This way you do not have to worry about variable text length.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  Test
</div>
```

If you were looking to style a single word and center it in a DIV view the snippet below:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  }
span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Another option would be, if you wanted the centered text to take up only so much of the containing element but still be centered you could do something like this:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay so if I give the div `display:inline;` how can I center it? `margin:auto;` does not work..?

Comment: To use `auto` for the left and right margin you need to specify a width.

Comment: and there is now comment for the browser to see how wide the element is without specifying a width?

Comment: What you can do to center a div is to put a certain width. Then, you can apply it margin: 0 auto; for example to have it centered

Comment: yes but the content can be variable so setting a certain width might not work for each and every case

Comment: So what's wrong with using `text-align: center;`? The text will remain centered and will drop to a new line if it doesn't fit it's container.

Comment: Right. Use `text-align` or use a span, which is an inline element by default, with auto margins. Don't force a block element to behave as an inline element for no reason.

Comment: @isherwood just clarifying for the OP, setting auto margins on an inline element won't center the inline element.

Comment: Ah! Right you are. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. By default, a div has the `display: block;` style applied. So, the default behavior of a block is to have 100% of its parent width.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="text-align: center">Test</div>
```

The div is 100% wide because div's are block elements, which means they span 100% wide. You would need to set the display to inline or inline block in order for it to 'stretch' to fit the content.

Comment: I know but that does not explain why the div automatically is 100% wide

Comment: The div is 100% wide because div's are block elements, which means they span 100% wide. You would need to set the display to inline or inline block in order for it to 'stretch' to fit the content.

Comment: @Quintile, add information to your question to make it more useful.